# Java KeepPushing Key game Listener

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I did a game where ship is moving like i wanna to move him. But my problem is when i have pushed a button. My ship is move but he have to wait a 1 sec to start moving in right way.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int jakiPrzycisk = e.getExtendedKeyCode();
    if(jakiPrzycisk == 39 )
    {
        kierunek="prawo";
        czyRuch = true;
    }
    if(jakiPrzycisk == 37)
    {
        kierunek="lewo";
        czyRuch = true;

    }
    if(jakiPrzycisk == 38)
    {
        kierunek="gora";
        czyRuch = true;

    }
    if(jakiPrzycisk == 40)
    {
        kierunek="dol";
        czyRuch = true;

    }
```

In game im checking if he will move with "czyRuch" and i move in right direction with "kierunek". There is a way to fastest reading from keybord ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "magic numbers". 37, 38, 39 40 mean nothing to anybody reading your code.

> But my problem is when i have pushed a button. My ship is move but he have to wait a 1 sec to start moving in right way.

Then you have a problem with code that is not posted. Java will respond to the KeyEvent right away.

However, there is a "delay" for repeating an event if the key is held down. This delay is OS dependent. If you need the ability to handle repeat events, then you should be using your own `Timer` to schedule these events. Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more thoughts on this subject as well as working code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes im sorry that was my mistake. Now i can show u an example where i've got a problem.

There is a example code

```
public class KeyTest extends JFrame implements KeyListener {


long start;
long end;
public KeyTest() {
    super("KeyListener Test");
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
    addKeyListener(this);
    start = System.nanoTime();;

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    end = System.nanoTime();;

    char c = evt.getKeyChar();
    System.out.print(c+" ");
    System.out.println(end-start);
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

}
```

}

and when i press any key for example "s". Ive got a

```
s 810407913
s 1312851842
s 1344314575
s 1377971356
s 1409969550
s 1441512603
s 1475051136
s 1507228263
```

between first and second "s" is a lot of difference. This is why my ship is stoping for a while when i wanna to press any key for few seconds but i dont know how to change that difference between time